# Moduli space of stable principal $G$-bundles on a compact Riemann surface.

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, riemann-surfaces, principal-bundles, moduli-space

Let $C$ be a compact Riemann surface. I'm looking for some references in order to try to understand what is the moduli space of stable principal $G$-bundles on $C$, where $G$ is a simple Lie group. Could you give me some references? For example if $G=U(1)$ and $\mathbb{C}P^1$ how can I describe the moduli space of stable principal $U(1)$-bundles on $\mathbb{C}P^1$?

Answer (score 1):

For rank $1$ Lie groups ($\mathbb{C} \mathbf{P}^1$ is not a Lie group by the way), you can look at Goldman-Xia, *Rank One Higgs Bundles and Representations of Fundamental Groups of Riemann Surfaces*

Comment: For me $C=\mathbb{C}P^1$...

Comment: Is there in general a ''basic'' paper on moduli space of stable principal $G$-bundles on compact Riemann surfaces?

Comment: I don't think there is a one standard reference. It's not too hard to find several relevant articles or notes by searching the web. Some will be more oriented towards such or such aspect/theory (algebraic geometry, flat connections, Higgs bundles, geometric structures, surface group representations...) In any case, the theory is quite hard and it's probably going to require reading more than one paper to digest the maths. I think the reference I gave you is a good idea to start (and it's probably "the" reference for rank 1). But maybe some other advice would be welcome, I'm not an expert.

Comment: NB: $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}\mathbf{P}^1$ is hardly acceptable ;)

Comment: $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is a compact Riemann surface!

Comment: I see, I thought you were talking about the group. You probably want to consider Riemann surfaces of negative Euler characteristic, otherwise the situation is probably degenerate but I haven't given it any thought, I'll let you do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can consult A. Ramanathan - *Stable Principal Bundles on a Compact Riemann Surface*.